# Why doesn't my fadeIn work?

Tags: jquery, animation

I have already tried to figure it out by using others stack overflow questions but it won't work. How can I animate something after the first animation is ready in jquery (with or without fadeIn)?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('div.sky').animate({height: '40em', opacity: '1'},5000, function() {
            $('div.grass').fadeIn({opacity: '1'},5000);
        });
});
```

The script is in my HTML document. I dont know if that might error something and the 'div.sky' works.

```
.sky {
background: deepskyblue;
width: 55%;
margin: auto;
opacity: 0;
}

.grass {
    background: lawngreen;
    width: 55%;
    margin: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 5em;
}
```

Comment: You can check if this executes by putting in a console.log() or something easy.

Comment: Checked in JSFiddle and seems its working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/buddhirameshi/5yx0n86a/ Isn't this what you want?

Comment: @BuddhiMadarasinghe I forgot to show my CSS, the opacity of grass needs to change but it still doesnt.

Comment: You need to use either ```animate({opacity})``` OR ```fadeIn()```on the grass div. Not ```fadeIn``` with paramaters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a working example with your code](https://jsfiddle.net/oe9gycvp/3/)

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('div.sky').animate({height: '10em', opacity: '1'},5000);
        $('div.grass').delay(5000).fadeIn();
});
```

CSS updated :

```
.grass {
    background: lawngreen;
    width: 55%;
    margin: auto;
    display:none;
    height: 5em;
}
```

`fadeIn()` works with `display` property, not `opacity`.

Then I add a `delay()` of the animation duration value to show the second div after animation complete.

**Docs :** 
`delay()` : https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: Please explain on setTimeout() and delay(), for the learning purposes. Thanks.

Comment: I add small explanation with a link to the API

Comment: Actually, the delay will STOP the effect until after 5000,```fadeIn(5000)``` is closer to what was asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Simply swap in `.animate()` for `.fadeIn()`. You're already taking care of the fade by setting `opacity`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.sky').animate({
    height: '40em',
    opacity: '1'
  }, 5000, function() {
    $('div.grass').animate({  // <---- changed to animate here
      opacity: '1'
    }, 5000);
  });
});
```

```css
.sky {
  background: deepskyblue;
  width: 55%;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0;
}
.grass {
  background: lawngreen;
  width: 55%;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sky"></div>
<div class="grass"></div>
```